# How to avoid bad synchronization between AJAX and the Database?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, database

I'm working on a web page that has multiple db inserts (toggles) through ajax.

In particular I implemented a vote system. Every time that the user hit an up or down button, this will update the database for example something similar like this:

```
if hit_up:
   if vote_up_exist:
       delete(vote_up)
   else:
       insert(vote_up)

# the same for hit_down, right!
```

If JavaScript and the Server gone slow and if the user is inpatient, he will hit the up or down vote button many times in a row and for some reasons the vote will be inserted as many times as hits and none deleted.

This is my $.ajax implementation:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/toggle_vote/",
    data:{
        'btn_id':btn_id,
        'up_vote':up, // true or false
        'down_vote':down, // true or false
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
         // Handle of images and vote count
    }
});
```

How can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: You could disable the button once an ajax call has fired.

Comment: Either disable the button until the server responded (I recommend this) or do the logic on the server side and only tell the server which button has been clicked.

Comment: don't accept same type of vote more than once per user account,